# Include dll in a xml schema

Tags: xml, visual-studio, biztalk

I am trying to avoid having a project containing all my schemas, and therefor I am trying to make one project for each schema. But the schemas need to to include each other.

Is it even possible to include a dll in a schema??

I have tried:

```
<xs:include schemaLocation="examplefile.dll" />
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To import a schema from another BizTalk project you use the imported schemas type-name as the schemaLocation.

[image: schema import from another assembly]

If you do not want to use the built in schema editor to do the import for you and you are unsure on the type-name it is easily found in the "Fully Qualified Name" property of the schema as show here:

[image: find the schema type-name]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to do that but you can reference each schema project in VS e.g.:

[image]

and then import or include the required schema thus:

[image]